# Find $P(z<Z\mid Z>0)$ given $Z\sim\operatorname N(0,1)$ using Law of Total Probability?

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution

How to calculate the CDF of symmetric random variable over the Y axis, given that random variable is greater than 0?

> Given $Z\sim\operatorname N(0,1),$ find $P(z<Z\mid Z>0)$

I tought of making a condition within the given condition. But $P(z<0)$ which I think shall be involved in the derived function is not something I understand how to write properly when again I write a condition inside a condition. I'd (mistakengly) say that $P(z<0)=0.5$ but this is 100% wrong. small $z$ is not Random Variable, it's just a variable. Could you help me calculate this and write down properly (preferably with condition inside a condition, so it will align with how I see this?)

EDIT: I was thinking of writing down something like this - 
$P(z<Z|Z>0)=P(z<0,z<Z|Z>0)P(z<0)+P(z>0,z<Z|Z>0)P(z>Z)$

EDIT2: Could you help me please particulary with $P(z>0,z<Z|Z>0)$? How to calculate it?

EDIT3: I understand z is just a variable, but there's for sure a proper way to write this using the same idea of Law of Total Probability.

Comment: @DavidPeterson You've confused $Z>0$ with $z>0$.

Comment: Yes, I did......

Comment: $z$ is *not* a variable, at least not in the sense of being a non-[degenerate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_distribution#Constant_random_variable) [random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable). Don't confuse it with $Z$!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the standard formula for conditional probability. You're trying to calculate$$\frac{P(z<Z\land Z>0)}{P(Z>0)}=\frac{P(Z>\max(z,\,0))}{1/2}=2\Phi(-\max(z,\,0)),$$where $\Phi$ is the $N(0,\,1)$ CDF. For $z\le0$, the result is $2\Phi(0)=1$; for $z>0$, the result is $2\Phi(-z)$.

Comment: Hi, I'm sure it is a correct answer but I don't understand the math involved with max/mins. I apologies I edited after you answered, I was editing the question through all this time. If you can, could you please refer to my misunderstanding under "EDIT2" where I ask about $P(z>0,z<Z|Z>0)$? This is the way I can understand, I just don't know how to calc this part.

Comment: @VitaliPom Your Edit 2 made the same mistake as a commenter, in which you replaced $Z>0$ with $z>0$. Can you see why $z<Z$ iff $Z>z$, and why $Z>z$ and $Z>0$ are both true iff $Z>\max(z,\,0)$?

Comment: I edited and added EDIT3 whereas I claimed I understand that mitake as you were posting the comment. I will try to ramp up quickly on that $Z>max(z,0)$ now.

Comment: ok. So is $Z>max(z,0)$ the proper way to write exactly the same thing that we all wrote and were mistaken with (alas commenter)? Is that the same idea..? Please confirmed. I think I've just hacked the DNA of those min/max functions I've not understood until now. [btw Phi might be confused with Characteristic Function as far as I know...]. Ok I apologies, I'm a little bit confused. Let me learn your answer and (hopefully) mark it as the answer to my question. Many thanks :)

Comment: @VitaliPom Your Edit 1 misstated the LTP: it should be $P(z<Z|Z>0)=P(z<Z|Z>0,\,z<0)P(z<0)+P(z<Z|Z>0,\,z\ge0)P(z\ge0)$.

Comment: This indeed clarifies the misunderstanding in part 3. OK I'm ramping up on all that you said. Won't bother you from now for long :) MANY MANY MANY Thanks!!!!!! (Sorry moderator :) , I apologies. Won't thank for much in comments from now on.)